# Paypal SDK Class Name Conflicts

Tags: cakephp, paypal, composer-php

I want to use Paypal Adaptive Payments and Paypal Adaptive Accounts libs in my CakePHP 2.4.x application.  I am loading them via composer.  My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"v3.6.106",
    "paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php":"v3.6.106"
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
}
}
```

Both libs contain Paypal/Types/Common/RequestEnvelope.php and for each lib they are different.  I'm running into a conflict with this class name where the right one isn't being used.  I believe the solution is to use autoload in my composer.json.  I've read the documentation and don't believe I'm using it correctly.  Here is what I'm attempting:

```
{
"require": {
    "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"v3.6.106",
    "paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php":"v3.6.106"
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AdaptivePaymentsLib\\": "Vendor/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/lib",
        "AdaptiveAccountsLib\\": "Vendor/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/lib"
    }
}
}
```

And in my controller I'm attempting to call RequestEnvelope like this:

$requestEnvelope = new AdaptivePaymentsLib\PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope("en_US");

It is not being found.  Active Accounts was only recently added to the project.  Previously getting the request envelope worked fine with $requestEnvelope = new PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope("en_US"); so it was only with the addition of the accounts which presented the conflict and caused the breakage.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that lead me to develop my own [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) years ago.  I've gotten lots of good feedback on it over the years, and it handles everything in the PayPal Classic API very easily.

Comment: @AndrewAngell: Why didn't you make it available via Composer? In this state it's next to useless if someone is relying on Composer - which all major frameworks do at this time.

Comment: @Sven, could I get some of your time to answer some questions I have about that?  I'm happy to pay for some consulting.

Comment: @AndrewAngell If you have questions, you know how to ask them here. If I happen to see them, I'll try to answer, but I don't think this is the place to negotiate consultancy.

Comment: @Sven, well, the thing is they're more general questions as opposed to code questions, so if I post them on SO it'll just get voted down.

Comment: @Sven, check it out:  https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/tree/composer

Answer (score 1):

You should not define autoloading for your dependencies - that is the task for them to solve.

If you look at the composer.json file for paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php, you see:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "PayPal\\Service": "lib/",
        "PayPal\\Types": "lib/"
    }
}
```

If you look at the same file in paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php, you see:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "PayPal\\Service": "lib/",
        "PayPal\\Types": "lib/"
    }
}
```

After installing, Composer creates a file `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` with this content:

```
return array(
    'PayPal\\Types' => array($vendorDir . '/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/lib', $vendorDir . '/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/lib'),
    'PayPal\\Service' => array($vendorDir . '/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/lib', $vendorDir . '/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/lib'),
    'PayPal' => array($vendorDir . '/paypal/sdk-core-php/lib'),
);
```

So both libraries are included here, and I have no doubt the autoloading will work.

You cannot really do something about the duplicate classes with different content. Did you open an issue on Github? Without making the developer team aware of this problem, it will never get solved.

As a hack, you could define a post-install and post-update script that deletes one of these files. See [the composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) for more details. Composer accepts either any shell command, or a static call to a PHP class. I'd go with the shell command here.